# Change SQL table design for Power BI dataset

Tags: sql, pivot, powerbi, powerquery, unpivot

I have a SQL table in the following format that I would like to use as a dataset in PowerBi:

[image]

I am trying to convert it into a condensed table like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to go about this whether it is as a SQL script or in Power BI?

Comment: Please provide data in table form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query editor, select all of the month columns (`Jan` - `Dec`) and choose Unpivot Columns under the Transform tab.

Once it's unpivoted, just filter out the zeros.